# How to concatinate multiple graphs on the same x y axis in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, matlab-figure

I have for loop that plots multiple graphs, whereby each graph has own window.
I would like to concatenate these graphs using only one graph and x y axis.

Could someone give an example?

Comment: using `hold on`

Comment: I use it. hold on does not concatenate the plots.

Comment: `hold on` should be the solution. Either go to  https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html for some examples and check wether you implemented it correctly or/and post a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What do you mean by "concatenate the plots"? Give an example with numbers

Comment: You probably call `figure` within the loop. If you use `hold on` you don't need to call `figure`, so remove it. If you give some more information about your data and the desired plots, you may get a solution that does not need a loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

The following code plots a few points in a single graph. You can place anything you'd like to plot in this plot() function.

```
x = [1,2,3,4];
y = [5,3,4,6];

figure; % Create a new figure window.
hold on;
for i = 1:length(x)
    plot(x(i), y(i), 'r*'); % Plot a red star.
end
```