# How to concatenate these subplots on one graph?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Here is the a simpler version of my code.

```
.....
ch_array = [36, 40, 44, 48, 149, 161];
figure;

for i=1:length(ch_array) 
    ch = ch_array(i);     
    subplot(3, 3, i);
    eval(sprintf('plot(mean_a_%d_f, ''r'')', ch));
    hold on;
    eval(sprintf('plot(mean_b_%d_f, ''b'')', ch));
    xlabel('Subcarrier (f)');
    ylabel('Absolute values');
    eval(sprintf('title(''Channel: %d'')', ch));
end
.....
```

The `mean_a` and `mean_b` depend on the `ch_array` so that as a result, there are `mean_a_36_f`, `mean_a_40_f`,..., `mean_a_161_f`  and the same thing with the `mean_b`.

This `for` loop plots graphs according to `ch_array`, the following figure:

[image]

As you can see, for each `ch_array` element is plotted the corresponding `mean_a_ch` and `mean_b_ch`.

Now, the purpose is these subplots to concatenate so that all are on one figure, but concatenated and not so how the `hold on` does. The concatenation should look like this:

[image]

where for the each concatenated plot will be denoted on the X axis, as can be seen on the pic.

Comment: This looks like your previous questions. If it is the same question, you should have edited your original questions [***#1***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721722/how-to-concatinate-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-x-y-axis-in-matlab) and [***#2***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737783/multiple-plots-coombine-and-concatenate-in-matlab) instead of posting as a new question

Comment: Yes, I am here new and I decided just to make a new post.

Comment: As mentioned before, you should have edited your original question. Also please *get rid of dynamic variable names* that have  led you to the evil `eval` and use matrices (or cell arrays/structure if using matrices isn't possible). Your code might seem to work but that's the worst thing that one can do to his code. http://i.imgur.com/XtcajQS.gif

Comment: and to answer your question, `hold on` will definitely work here. You just need to add some offset in the values of the x-axis. However the xticks in the figure you uploaded are not in accordance with the original graphs

Comment: The problem is, I cannot control the dynamic variable manually. Because the elements in ch_array can be different. eval make possible to init the dynamic variable and then read out its content and plot.

Comment: It *is* possible with the options that I mentioned in my earlier comment. Structure and cell arrays are always here for the rescue if using matrices is not possible. However I am also very positive that simple matrices (possibly 3D if not 2D) can be used here. It seems that you have created 161 dynamic variables for `mean_a` and 161 dynamic variables for `mean_b`. If the content of these dynamic variables is 1x1, use a single vector to keep all these 161 elements and select each of them via matrix indexing. if the content is not 1x1, use a 3-D array.

Comment: @MarkDelphi I left a comment [on an answer of one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737783/multiple-plots-coombine-and-concatenate-in-matlab#comment76471869_44744913). I linked there [to an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226214/matlab-loop-through-the-values-of-a-list-from-who-function/40226542#40226542) that shows how you can use `load` to put all your variables into a struct. Once you have a struct, you can dynamically access its fields usings strings, and you can skip the **very dangerous and slow and ugly** `eval`.

Comment: As for your question: `hold on` doesn't do magic, it will only let you plot multiple plots in the same axes. If you want to plot multiple datasets shifted into the same axes, you need to shift the coordinates yourself. Keep track of the `numel` of each dataset, and use an explicit `plot(x,y)` syntax to plot later datasets not as a function of `1:numel(y)` (which is what `plot(y)` does), but as a function of `x=offset:offset+numel(y)-1`.

Comment: And if you didn't notice, [^that^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44748386/how-to-concatenate-these-subplots-on-one-graph#comment76478676_44748386) exactly what I suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44744913/2627163) to your previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems. I'll start with the one you *didn't* ask about, since I'm worried you'll stop reading once I answer the other one.

You should **not** be using `eval` unless it's really necessary, and it's never necessary. `eval` is slow and insecure. If you `eval` malicious code, it can easily do serious harm to your system. In this case this is unlikely, but still using `eval` prevents MATLAB's just-in-time compiler to be able to optimize anything in the code inside, so you'll get the worst possible performance.

Now, you're claiming that you're stuck with `eval` because the variables are already set up dynamically. Note that this is a perfect example of an XY problem: you shouldn't end up with these data in the first place. Do them differently. If you're not in control of data creation, keep hitting the head of the person who is, so that they stop.

*Anyway*, once the damage is done, you can still quickly recover from the `eval` pit of doom. You need to save and reload your variables, which allows you to push them into a struct. This is nice, because struct fields [can be accessed dynamically](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html). Rewriting your original:

```
tmpfile = 'tmp.mat';
save(tmpfile,'mean_*_*_f'); % save relevant variables to tmp mat file
dat = load(tmpfile); % reload them into a struct named dat

ch_array = [36, 40, 44, 48, 149, 161]; % we could deduce these programmatically
figure;

for i=1:length(ch_array) 
    ch = ch_array(i);     
    subplot(3, 3, i);
    plot(dat.(sprintf('mean_a_%d_f',ch)), 'r'); % look, Ma, no eval!
    hold on;
    plot(dat.(sprintf('mean_b_%d_f',ch)), 'b');
    xlabel('Subcarrier (f)');
    ylabel('Absolute values');
    title(sprintf('Channel: %d',ch)); % seriously, this DID NOT need eval
end
```

---

Now, for your question. The problem is that `plot(y)` with this simple syntax plots `y` as a function of `1:numel(y)`: essentially `plot(1:numel(y),y)`. What you want to do is *manually* shift the `x` points for each data set so they don't overlap:

```
figure;

offset = 0;
midpoints = zeros(size(ch_array));
for i=1:length(ch_array) 
    ch = ch_array(i);     

    % deduce data to plot
    tmpdat_a = dat.(sprintf('mean_a_%d_f',ch));
    tmpdat_b = dat.(sprintf('mean_b_%d_f',ch));
    x_a = offset+1:offset+numel(tmpdat_a);
    x_b = offset+1:offset+numel(tmpdat_b);

    % plot
    plot(x_a, tmpdat_a, 'r');
    hold on;
    plot(x_b, tmpdat_b, 'b');

    % store xtick position
    midpoints(i) = mean(mean(x_a), mean(x_b));

    % increment offset
    offset = offset + numel(max([tmpdat_a, tmpdat_b])) + 10; % leave a border of width 10, arbitrary now
end

xlabel('Subcarrier (f)');
ylabel('Absolute values');
xticks(midpoints);
xticklabels(arrayfun(@num2str, ch_array, 'uniformoutput', false));
title('All channels');
```