# How to convert zeros into NaN and then take mean afterwards

Tags: matlab, matrix, split, printf, mean

I have one big 5D matrix and I want to split the matrix in 10 parts containing 57 rows and 92 columns and then take the means of each matrix (10 matrices) while ignoring zeros. I am trying this one example. While applying the second loop, `Undefined function M_ii` error is showing in Matlab.

```
val = zeros(57,92,1,1,10);

% Create N matrices
N = 10;

for i = 1:N
    eval(sprintf('M_%d = val(:,:,1,1,%d);', i, i));
end

for i = 1:10
    M_i(M_i==0)=NaN;
    Mean_1=mean(M_i);
    mean_1=mean(Mean_1,2);
end
```

Comment: Always use multidimensional arrays, or structs with dynamic fields. If you're stuck with dynamic variable names [there's a way out still](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44749014/5067311) but you can just stop creating them. Never use eval!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect variable names to be generated/changed like that and of course you'd need [*another ugly way*](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/) to do that; just like the one you used to create them in the first place. So please never ever make dynamic variables. If you ever think that you need dynamic variables, you need to [*think again*](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval).

You can directly use [`mean`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) along the first and second dimensions. You'd need the `omitnan` flag after replacing zeros with `NaN` to exclude zeros from the computation of mean.

```
val(val==0) = NaN;
mean_1 = mean(val,1,'omitnan');
mean_2 = mean(val,2,'omitnan');
```

---

By the way, to remove singleton dimensions (3rd and 4th in your provided example), you can use [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html).

Comment: the zeros are still there, they have not been converted to NaN.

Comment: do you have floating point values? do you see zeros if you change your `format`? enter `format long` and then check if you have zeros

Comment: I do not have floating point values. I have scalar values 14367, 14657....and so on in the matrix. I enter  **format long** as you have said and zeros are still there.

Comment: I checked my original matrix and realized that it is uint16 class matrix containing 57 rows and 92 columns. That is why, the Zeroes are not being converted to NaN for taking mean. Can you suggest me for this. Thank you

Comment: @VaishaliJain So that was the issue. You should've mentioned that before. You cannot have `NaN` in uint16 class. So convert that to double first i.e.  `val =double(val);` and then run the code. It should work fine. Later at then end, if you want to have result in uint16 class, you can convert back.

Comment: Now the Zeroes values have been converted into NaN but the error _Too many input arguments_
 is coming in taking mean **mean_1 = mean(lst,1,'omitnan');**

Comment: @VaishaliJain what is `lst`?  and which version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: MATLAB Version: 8.1.0.604 (R2013a)
MATLAB License Number: 724504
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64

Comment: lst is my file name.

Comment: @VaishaliJain You were meant to use `val` after its conversion to double.; not a filename. Regarding the version issue, looking at the old docs, I've come to know that `'omitnan'` flag was not present in the older versions. If you have 'Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox' installed in your MATLAB. You can use `nanmean` i.e. `mean_1 = nanmean(val,1);` for mean along the first dimension or  `mean_2 = nanmean(val,2);` for mean along the second dimension.